# WebClient (spring-boot-starter-webflux) sends request to incorrect url

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-8

I have two small apps, a client and a service.

Service is using -> http://dev.security.api.com:8080/api/

Client is using -> http://dev.security.com/

Using WebClient from “spring-boot-starter-webflux”, I faced the following issue.

```
Connection refused: dev.security.api.com/127.0.0.1:8080
```

I am unable to understand why it is using a different url.

The code is:

```
WebClient client2 = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl("http://dev.security.api.com:8080/api")
        .build();
```

I am using docker and they are running in two different containers.

Running the applications individually work fine, but when I am trying to send a request from client to the service. I am getting the error above.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is at the ports

How to debug it:

1. Create a test *curl* request
2. Call it from the same environment (docker container)
3. If error then check **active open ports**
4. When curl is okay - implement it inside Java code